# Free(): Invalid Pointer error while trying to upload multiple layers in cartoview?

Tags: python, django

I have installed cartoview and trying to upload multiple layer files (total 6) in cartoview, but when i upload it then this error occurs:

> Free(): Invalid Pointer
> Aborted (core dumped)

I tried to find the solution to the problem but it was not found on the web. Can someone kindly help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, i ran the following commands:

> sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal4

> export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4"

> sudo apt update -y; sudo apt upgrade -y;

and the files uploaded successfully.